# Porting Oracle SQL to PostgreSQL - MERGE INTO

Tags: postgresql

What I'm mostly doing these days is converting an Oracle SQL database into a PostgreSQL (9.1.6) database.

The most common issues that I tend to come across are as follows:

```
1. decode --> case when
2. nvl --> coalesce
3. (+) --> outer join
4. connect by prior --> connectby function with tablefunc contrib module.
5. merge into --> ???
etc...
```

I am currently skimming through the PostgreSQL manual and funnily enough there seems to be no `MERGE INTO` statement (or any direct substitutions for it).

I am aware that PL/pgSQL could be used as an alternative but that would mean a lot of extra workload for me. Is there something that I'm missing about this?

Comment: There is no simple merge replacement. For reasons, and possible solutions check this [blogpost](http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/).

Comment: 4) `connect by` --> recursive common table expression: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert, on duplicate update (postgresql)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-postgresql)

Comment: Old question, but I'm downvoting because there is no explanation of what `MERGE INTO` does, and how the OP wants to use it, making it hard to come up with a meaningful answer.

Comment: Upvoting, because MERGE is a very widely used command in Oracle SQL, and this is a valid question that crops up quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple replacement, and certainly not for 9.1.

The best option is to upgrade to 9.2 and look at writeable CTE's.  These allow you to multi-stage write operations in a similar manner.  For example, you could:

```
WITH up (UPDATE foo set bar = 'baz' where id > 1000
         returning id)
INSERT INTO foo(id, bar) 
SELECT s, 'baz'
  FROM generate_sequence(1001, 10000) s
 WHERE s NOT IN (select id from up);
```